# Least norm solution to a set of linear equations

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a set of linear equations $M x = y$ where there are infinitely many solutions. I want to find a solution $x$ with the smallest $l_2$ norm $\|x\|_2$. Is there an efficient way to do this? Using `Minimize` with constraints is too slow while `NMinimize` tells me that there is no solution (even though `LinearSolve` can find one)

I could find a solution using

```
LinearSolve[M, b]
```

but this can give me an arbitrary one, while I need the one with smallest possible $l2$ norm.

Note that `LeastSquares` solves a different problem -- it minimizes the norm of the error, not the norm of the solution.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Code for what? I am asking if there is a way to do something. If I knew what the code is, I would not be asking.

Comment: "NMinimize tells me that there is no solution",so what is your code.BTW, What is `M`?

Comment: @user2316602 An example of your equations in Mathematica code, as a very minimum starting point. You also mention that you tried Minimize and NMinimize, so you must have *some* example and *some* code you could share. If you give people something to play around with, you will stand a greater chance to get the help you seek.

Comment: I added code that finds an arbitrary solution

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example, not a generality. Give an example for `M` and `b`. Show the code for which you say `NMinimize` returns no solution. You are asking for help and we are telling you what we need to help you. What is the point of resisting sharing what we need to help *you*?

Comment: if there is an elegant way of doing it, there is no need to see an example where non-elegant ways fail...

Comment: You are just alienating the people trying to help you. Good luck.

Comment: Have you looked at `QuadraticOptimization`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a standard fact that `x = PseudoInverse[M].b` does what I think you want, namely: Return an `x` that minimizes `Norm[M.x-b]`, and among those `x` return the unique one that minimizes `Norm[x]`. In particular if there exists a solution $x$ of $Mx = b$, as you are assuming in your question, then this will return the unique solution `x` that minimizes `Norm[x]`. The math background for this is the [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

But I believe `x = LeastSquares[M,b]` will produce the same `x` for numeric matrices at least. Let us check this in an example. Let me generate a $6 \times 5$ matrix `M` with rank $3$, and a vector:

```
SeedRandom[1];
r[size_]:=RandomInteger[{-1,1},size];
M=r[{6,3}].r[{3,5}];
b=r[{6}];
```

You can check that `M` does indeed have rank $3$. And you can then check that

```
x = PseudoInverse[M].b
x = LeastSquares[M,b]
```

return exactly the same vector.

If you want to check explicitly that `Norm[x]` is minimized, you just have to check that `x` is orthogonal to the nullspace, and in fact the following evaluates to zero:

```
NullSpace[M].x
```

Remarks:

- I have restricted to real matrices and vectors, but the answer is almost identical in the complex case.
- I have worked with matrices with exact entries (rational numbers) to avoid subtleties related to the pseudoinverse when a matrix with non-exact entries (floating point numbers) has a very small singular value and so on.
- The documentation for [LeastSquares](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeastSquares.html) does not, I think, say explicitly that `LeastSquares` always matches the result of `PseudoInverse`, so perhaps it does not for symbolic matrices or in some other cases.

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution with the pseudoinverse is exactly what I was looking for. Neat!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, this is what you're looking for:

Inputs for a problem of the form `mat.x == y`:

```
mat = RandomReal[1, {2, 4}]
y = RandomReal[1, {2}]
```

Setting up arguments for `QuadraticOptimization`:

```
dimx = Dimensions[mat][[2]];
{q, c} = {IdentityMatrix[dimx], ConstantArray[0, dimx]};
{a, b} = {ConstantArray[0, {1, dimx}], {0}};
{aeq, beq} = {mat, -y};
```

Result:

```
x = QuadraticOptimization[{q, c}, {a, b}, {aeq, beq}]
```

Check that it's a solution:

```
mat.x - y
```

> {-5.45434*10^-11, 5.47102*10^-11}